# Bash string comparison not working

Tags: linux, bash, variables, scripting, ubuntu

I have the following Bash function:

```
checkForUpdates() {
    checkLatest
    ret=$?
    if [ $ret != 0 ]; then
        return $ret
    fi
    count=0
    for i in $(ssh $__updateuser@$__updatehost "ls $__updatepath/*${latest}*"); do
        file="${i##$__updatepath}"
        echo "$file" >> $__debuglog
        if [ -f $__pkgpath/$file ]; then
            remoteHash=$(ssh $__updateuser@$__updatehost "md5sum -b < $__updatepath/${file}")
            localHash=$(md5sum -b < $__pkgpath/$file)
            echo "${remoteHash:0:32} = ${localHash:0:32}" >> $__debuglog
            if [ "${remoteHash:0:32}" != "${localHash:0:32}" ]; then
                files[$count]=$file
                count=$(($count + 1))
                echo "Hashes not matched, adding $i" >> $__debuglog
            fi
        else
            files[$count]=$file
            count=$(($count + 1))
            echo "$file missing" >> $__debuglog
        fi
    done

    # Verify that the files array isn't empty.
    if [ $count != 0 ]; then
        return 0
    else
        return 33
    fi
}
```

For some reason, the remoteHash/localHash comparison always returns true. I added the echo so that I could see the values of the hashes and they are definitely different and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong. I have tried different operators with no success and it is driving me crazy!

Comment: Try running with `bash -x <command>`.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm making heavy use of dialog with this script and it keeps removing the output. does -x send to stdout or stderr? If it is stderr I could pipe it to a file I believe.

Comment: Nevermind, it is stderr.

Comment: Not sure what happened but it suddenly started working.

Comment: I hate when that happens! Nice code BTW. Good luck.

Comment: @DanArmstrong Instead of adding `SOLVED` to the title, post the solution which solved your problem, and mark ik as the accepted answer.

Comment: @RobW At the time that I posted the question, I was not yet allowed to answer my own questions due to a new user restriction.

Answer (score 3):

this isn't related to your question but more of general advice, first and most important [you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) instead use `find -print0` here's an example: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

also consider using `[[` instead of `[` see: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031

now regarding your code, this part:

```
checkLatest
ret=$?
if [ $ret != 0 ]; then
    return $ret
fi
```

could be written simply as:

```
checkLatest || return
```

and you don't need to keep a counter on the index of the array, if you initialize the var as an empty array like `files=()` you can then append elements to it with `files+=("$file")` you can get the count with `"${#files[@]}"`

Comment: Thank you much for the advice. Unfortunately I am no longer allocated time to maintain the scripts but I will definitely keep the input in mind for later projects.